# Can't get div to 100% height?

Tags: html, css

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, and I can't figure out how to Google it because a common mistake is very prevalent. **I have the parent's height explicitly set**, but I can't get #main-sub-content 's height to 100%.

Here's the page:
http://coloryourspot.vadremix.com/

And the corresponding CSS:
http://coloryourspot.vadremix.com/styles/primary/main.css

Can anyone spot the issue?

**Solved:** The problem was the parent element had height:auto!important;

Comment: It's because it's floated. There are some tutorials online (google) for 2 column css layouts using floats with 100% height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this attribute:

```
div#main-content{height:auto!important}
```

and things works fine in Chrome.

But since your `#main-sub-content` is `min-height:100%`, your `#footer-clear` will be put out of screen. You may have to work that out later.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is being caused by footer-clear

Chrome Developer tools or Firebug in FF will always help you find these issues.